# Можно-ли анимировать прорисовку иконки fontAwesome внутри свойства content тега <i>?

Tags: css3, vue.js, анимация, fontawesome, quasar.js

Использую фреймворк quasar с подключенным font-awesome, захотелось сделать прорисовку иконок, но стандартные способы не подходят, т.к. там идёт стилизация тега svg, а в случае с font-awesome происходит отрисовка тега i с классом нужной иконки, внутри которого в content записан идентификатор иконки, соответственно обычный stroke-dasharray и stroke-dashoffset не работает. Подскажите, может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Прим HTML: `<i class="q-icon fal fa-arrow-alt-right q-tab__icon" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"> </i>`
Прим CSS: `.fa-arrow-alt-right::before { content: "\f356"; }`

Comment: Маловероятно что можно анимировать svg которое не находится *физически* в `DOM` дереве.

Comment: `Можно-ли аниммировать прорисовку иконки fontAwesome` **`внутри свойства content тега <i>?`** почти. `:before` в котором и располагается `content` прекрасно кастомизируется чистым CSS, в том числе и аниммируется как с `keyframes` так и с `transition`. причем `transition` может задаваться как для всех свойств, так и для какого то одного определенного. p.s. с `fa\q` не работал, так что, могут быть подводные камни.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, нельзя. [fontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/docs/desktop/) это шрифт, он не анимируеться, так как вы описали. Вы можете вытащить SVG элемент конкретной иконки и уже его анимировать так как вам будет удобно.